# How to covert a json array string to json object

Tags: java, android, json

```
[{"ID":"1",
"Profileimg":"http:\/\/192.168.0.104\/JSON\/jsontestpics\/mr-robot-wallpaper-3.jpg",
"Heading":"Heading Test 1",
"Timestamp":"2016-08-28 11:06:00",
"Tag":"ACM",
"Content":"contentttttFifty-seven tornadoesFifty-seven tornadoesFifty-seven tornadoesFifty-seven",
"Contentimg":"http:\/\/192.168.0.104\/JSON\/jsontestpics\/mr-robot-wallpaper-3.jpg"}]
```

Need to convert this Array string into JSONObject in java

THIS IS THE REQUEST CODE, response from the server is fine but it is string type,how to convert this response string into json object.

```
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Home_posts_config.DATA_URL_1,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                            //Dismissing progress dialog
                            loading.dismiss();
                            Log.d("asdfas","response-__"+response);

                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.d("asdfas","response_errorrrr"+error.getMessage());
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERRORR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loading.dismiss();
                        }
                    }){

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("heading", hdtxt);
                    params.put("tag",tgtxt);
                    params.put("fetchid",idd);

                    return params;
                }


            };

            //Creating request queue
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

            //Adding request to the queue
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
```

Comment: I don't see where the JSON is in the code you posted. Can you post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first convert it into JSONArray as you get JSON schema is in JSONArray.

```
JSONArray jsonArrayResult = new JSONArray(response);
```

Now use you get JSONObject from this jsonArrayResult.

```
for(int i =0; i<jsonArrayResult.length();i++)
{
JSONObject jsonResult =jsonArrayResult.get(i);
// Do what ever you want to do with jsonResult.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that:

```
    String response = "[{\"ID\":\"1\", \"Profileimg\":\"http://192.168.0.104/JSON/jsontestpics/mr-robot-wallpaper-3.jpg\", \"Heading\":\"Heading Test 1\", \"Timestamp\":\"2016-08-28 11:06:00\", \"Tag\":\"ACM\", \"Content\":\"contentttttFifty-seven tornadoesFifty-seven tornadoesFifty-seven tornadoesFifty-seven\", \"Contentimg\":\"http://192.168.0.104/JSON/jsontestpics/mr-robot-wallpaper-3.jpg\"}]";

    JSONObject array = new JSONObject("{'data':"+response+"}");

    System.out.println(array.get("data"));
```